# How do I get the thumbprint of an SSH2 public key on windows?

Tags: windows, ssh

I have a SSH2 public key with a .PUB extension and when viewed in notepad it has this header:

```
 ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

How do I view the thumbprint of this key?

I've attempted `ssh-keygen -lf key.pub` but that returns: "Is not a valid key file".  (I got the binaries for ssh-keygen from github's standard shell.

I'm a bit new to SSH/SSH2 and not sure what the difference is, or if I'm using the wrong version of a tool for the wrong version of a public key.

Comment: Are you using Git Bash? What line-endings does the file have?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you made your key with the PuTTY Key Generator (PuTTYgen).  To get the OpenSSH pubkey format, edit it with PuTTYgen (right click on the `.ppk` file and click on "edit").

At the top of the window, you'll see the "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file" text box.  The text should start with `ssh-rsa AAA` (assuming an [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29) key).  Copy that text and save it as your public key.  This is what you need.  You'll also find your key fingerprint in here.

Here's a screen shot of what I'm describing:
[image: PuTTYgen]